# Is there a way to record a page view when using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

Is there a way to record that a user to my site who click on the "more info" button on a modal is recorded in a database. What I am trying to do is get an idea of which scholarships the students are most interested in and record that data. The page is produced using MySQL and PHP and bootstrap, so I understand that there is an issue with sending the data back to the server because the page has already been rendered by the server.

Here is a screenshot of part of the page.

[image]

I realize that PHP and javascript deal with data in different ways, but I guess my question is how might I accomplish this, or is this even possible using the existing PHP and bootstrap. My initial thought is to attach an event to the "more info" button but then the page needs to be refreshed to get the data to the server which would be confusing for the students using the site.

Any help with how this might be done would be greatly appreciated.

So here is the code that I have so far.

The modal code: (* I didn't include all of it as I don't think it necessary)

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" onclick="saveData(<? echo $row['id'].",". "1";  ?>)" 
**class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="savedata" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#myModal<? echo $row['id']; ?>">More Information.</button>**

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal<? echo $row['id']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
```

And here is the Ajax code

```
<script>
function window.saveData(){
var name=$('#savedata').val();


$.ajax({
   type:"post",
   url:"includes/post_scholarship_count.php",
   data:"nm="+name,
   success: function(msg){
    alert('Success Insert data');
   }

});
}
</script>
```

When I inspect the page running on the server I get an error

Uncaught ReferenceError: saveData is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (university.php:182)

Which is:

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveData(826,1)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" 
id="savedata" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal826">More Information. 
</button>
```

I am guessing that the issue something to do with the modal button but I am not even sure you can do this in such a manner.

Again thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use Ajax to do it.
Create a page or function to receive a post request with php.
And then when you click the button you send a post to this php file

```
//ajax script
$.post( "url_to_file.php", { name: value} ).done(function( 
    //console.log(data);
})


//php script in url_to_file.php
if(isset($_POST['name']){
    $value = $_POST['name'];
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yes I see how this might work, thanks so much for the help. The page would not need to refresh for this to send the data?

Comment: Yes, with Ajax it won't need to refresh the page.